# Netlogo displaying pxcor and or pycor in a monitor

Tags: netlogo

**I am trying to display the coordinates or a turtle in monitors.

I cant seem to figure out how to do this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a monitor can be used to display a reporter, you can make use of the [`to-report`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#to-report) primitive to create your own reporter that returns the coordinates. For example, to have your monitor display "Xcor: [xcor of turtle 0] Ycor: [ycor of turtle 0]" you could use the code below:

```
to-report coords
  let x [xcor] of turtle 0 
  let y [ycor] of turtle 0

  report ( word "Xcor: " x " Ycor: " y) 
end
```

Then, have your monitor display the reporter `coords` and you will have a dynamic view of the coordinates of turtle 0.